# How to stop TextBox from expanding indefinitely in wfp

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following control:

[image]

Which is defined by the following code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="VariantMeshEditor.Views.EditorViews.Util.BrowsableItemView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:common="clr-namespace:CommonDialogs.Common;assembly=CommonDialogs"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="self">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <common:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToHiddenConverter" TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50" Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0"  Content="{Binding LabelName, ElementName=self}" Width="{Binding LabelLength, ElementName=self}"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1">:</Label>

        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" x:Name="CheckBox" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
        <Border x:Name="b" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <TextBox  Grid.Column="3" IsReadOnly="{Binding PathTextReadOnly, ElementName=self}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding PathText, ElementName=self}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=b}"/>

        <Button Grid.Column="4" Visibility="{Binding DisplayRemoveButton,  ElementName=self, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}" Command="{Binding Remove, ElementName=self}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" >Remove</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="5" Visibility="{Binding DisplayBrowseButton,  ElementName=self, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}" Command="{Binding Browse, ElementName=self}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" >Browse</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="6" Visibility="{Binding DisplayPreviewButton, ElementName=self, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}" Command="{Binding Preview, ElementName=self}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" >Preview</Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My problem is that when I expand the control where this control is used and then make is smaller again, the TextBox does not get smaller. Any idea on how to resolve this? I want to label to always be fixed to the left side and the buttons to the right with the Texbox occupying whatever is left.

Normal:
[image]

Expanded:
[image]

Made smaller again:
[image]

Comment: How do you use your `BrowsableItemView`? Please show the code for your window, too. The error does not seem to be in your user control markup.

Answer (score 0):

The XAML you've posted doesn't have anything obviously wrong, and seems to work fine.  I created a minimal example that doesn't have any bindings or code that we don't have access to, this is below.  If you paste this into a clean WPF App you'll see it expands and shrinks without problem.

This means the problem is likely to be in code that you haven't shared somewhere (or I'm just missing it).  If you can [modify this example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show the issue someone may be able to help you.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="self">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50" Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="0"  Content="Label" Width="40"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1">:</Label>

                <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" x:Name="CheckBox" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
                <Border x:Name="b" Grid.Column="3"/>
                <TextBox  Grid.Column="3" IsReadOnly="False" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Type here"/>

                <Button Grid.Column="4" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" >Remove</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column="5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" >Browse</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column="6" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50" >Preview</Button>
            </Grid>
        </UserControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```